# Toshiba Blu-ray Disk Player no longer works after upgrading to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, blu-ray, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba computer, with a built in Blu-Ray drive. The system came with Windows 7, but I have updated it to Windows 8. The computer came with Toshiba Blu-ray Disk Player installed to play Blu-Rays, however it no longer works properly.

When I upgraded I followed the instructions that the manufacturer provided, installing all the necessary drivers and software (minus the unrelated and unnecessary bloat) that were required.

Now my disk drive works, it reads CD/DVDs fine, and I can even browse the file system of any disk including BDs. I can see no problem with the device, and I tried multiple disks that I can confirm are working. But when I try to play it, the player simply shows a black screen with no audio. The title/chapter lists are populated, as if it was reading the disk, but no media is played.

My initial thought was the player was out of date, so I went to their site and downloaded the latest version. No dice. So I tried a couple of other players. The trial for PowerDVD was able to play the disks, so I know it's a software issue.

Customer support was a bust. I've installed all Windows Updates, just in case they would fix it, no difference.

#### System Specifications:

- Toshiba Qosmio F755-3D350 laptop
- Windows 8 Pro x64 (with Media Center upgrade).

Comment: I haven't heard of PotPlayer before, but it appears to be free software. Blu-ray movies are encrypted and require playing licensing fees to get the decryption keys. Due to this it seems highly unlikely that it would be able to play commercial Blu-Ray Movies.

Comment: It was recommended by a reliable source, PowerDVD trial has a similar failure however.

Comment: Interesting. I just had a quick look at the trial page for PowerDVD and it says the that it restricts the playback of some protected content. Have a try at using [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/). It should be able to decrypt the movie and save a copy to your computer. If you're able to playback that file (I'd recommend [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) ), I believe it would almost certainly be an encryption issue.

Comment: Well epic weirdness abounds. MakeMKV works. Also, now PowerDVD works too (PC crashed for unrelated reason, so reboot fixed that I am guessing). . . But still not the manufacturers player (the one that comes with my computer, and won't cost me 60 bucks). Grr. . .

Comment: Have you even tried installing the appropiate codecs?

Comment: @arielnmz That is certainly not the issue. Blu-Rays can be played, just not with a specific player.

Comment: Just that some players can play them doesn't mean codecs aren't the issue. As I've already said in a comment, some come with built-in codecs so you don't have to install them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know blu-ray discs do not play natively in win8 and you have to get the right codecs.
Try this, and let us know.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/699817-playing-blu-ray-discs-windows-8-using-vlc-media-player.html

Comment: This is irrelevant, neither do DVDs. However third party software (like the mentioned player from the manufacturer) can play them just fine. As a point of fact however, I did attempt to use VLC. It crashes immediately if I attempt to play a Blu-Ray.

Comment: You metioned it crashed immediately but did you get the KEYDB.cfg file?

Comment: Yes, I installed both files correctly (according to 3 different guides at least). I am pretty sure the problem is something deeper.

Comment: @zeel most players come with builtin codecs, that's why you think codecs aren't the issue but they most certainly are. Have you even tried installing them?

Comment: @arielnmz I know about codecs, I am certain that isn't my problem in this situation. Playing a Blu-Ray requires that the disk be decrypted, the needed software for this has to be licensed. Thus BD players are not free. My problem is that I have one that came with the computer that no longer works. I can buy another one (PowerDVD) and everything will be fine. But why drop $60 on something I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the vendor to get the appropriate drivers and software for your player that function on Windows 8.

Comment: I tried that. There customer support is useless. I pointed this out in my question.

Comment: @zeel - You only said you attempted to contact.  Its unfair to downvote valid advice.

Comment: I didn't downvote it.

Answer (score -1):

In order to play blu-ray on pc, you need blu-ray drive and an blu-ray player software, vlc is the best free tool for your choice, and ufusoft blu-ray player is an alternative for enjoying retail blu-ray disc/iso files on pc. http://www.ufusoft.com/blu-ray-player/

Comment: Too bad this company is spamming a lot. Don't buy from companies like that.